# CSS not applying to GH-pages

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I've been trying to get my CSS to apply to my gh-pages but I've found myself going in circles.

This is the original setup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.production.css">
```

(my CSS is in a CSS folder just inside of my root)

I've tried the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.production.css">
```

I also tried moving my CSS to my root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.production.css">
```

Lastly, I tried using my main CSS file rather than the one you see above. No luck.

All of my changes were made in my main branch, pushed, merged with gh-pages. Not able to see what I'm doing wrong, I am still new at this! n_n"

https://honeybutterbear.github.io/portfolio-website/index.html
https://github.com/Honeybutterbear/portfolio-website

Comment: I see that you are including the "js/tota11y.min.js", which works. 
So the path should be "css/style.production.css".
If opening the DevTools (im using chrome), then under the sources tab you can see the path seems to be correct, but it cannot find the file specified. 
So i think you maybe have uploaded a empty file or no file at all :-)

if it was exisiting, then you should be able to navigate to:
https://honeybutterbear.github.io/portfolio-website/css/style.production.css

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! Using DevTools helped me understand what the issue was a lot more. I didn't figure it out with github, so I moved ahead and uploaded my site to my host. I had to adjust my folder names to lowercase, correct the file perms, and it started working https://lportee-1.bluehoststaff.com/devproject2/About_Lauren.html Still have no idea how to adjust things on the github side tho...

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I can see with your link is the case. Try using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Css/style.production.css">
```

Since that is how you named your folder, I just tested it with inspect element so might not work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! I really appreciate it. I wasn't able to correct github, but I was able to find success after uploading my site to my host and making adjustments to file perms from there... https://lportee-1.bluehoststaff.com/devproject2/About_Lauren.html works for me now :)